# Drupal 7 - Adding fields in User node or link node to the current user?

Tags: drupal-7, nodes

I'm designing a website in drupal in which users would be able to set their preferences in different areas. e.g. Fav. Games:.

Now I want these preferences to show in a seperate menu option for the users to fillout. I created a seperate node but I need someone to advise me how to link it with the users. Or if there is any other better way please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Profile 2 module: http://drupal.org/project/profile2

You can create profile fields with your different areas, which will be assigned to that user.

Comment: Thanks... I'll check that in detail.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7, you can attach fields to any entity that is declared as fieldable; that includes users.

Just add the fields you need from admin/config/people/accounts/fields.

Comment: Yes, but I would need to provide users 2 seperate links. One for their account settings and other for their profile settings. How can I do that?

Comment: In Drupal, there is just the link to edit a user account (`http://example.com/user/<uid>/edit`), not one for the account settings, and one for the profile settings.

Comment: yes, But I want to have 2 seperate menus or may be 3 because the account setting page will be much larger than usual.